# Command To Manually Index Redis Georadius Query?

Tags: redis

I saw a blog that claims to search 1.7 million coordinates in a redis database in 10 milliseconds, but my system is taking 1.7 seconds to search 400 thousand coordinates.

Does anyone know of a command to manually index redis GEO data or am I missing something?

redis_version:3.2.6

Thanks!

Comment: Does the blog provide the setup used? What are you using? How many points are you returning? How large is the search radius? There are many factors that can affect performance - what's your baseline PING? In any case, there's no special command/manual indexing/voodoo - just GEOADD and GEORADIUS

Comment: @ItamarHaber Nothing special with the setup. Returning < 10,000 points and same performance when I return 10. Search radius is 50km. I'm testing on an AWS ubuntu server so PING is strong. Thanks for your response - it's helpful to know I didn't miss something in the docs.